# Is '+=' between strings converted to StringBuilder calls sometimes?

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

Let's take this piece of code as an example:

```
public void func(string x1, string x2, string x3) {
    string concat = "";
    concat += x1;
    concat += x2;
    concat += x3;
}
```

Is the compiler smart enough to convert that to a series of StringBuilder calls?

Comment: Please [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#addition-assignment-operator-) the documents.

Comment: StringBuilder isn't a part of the C# language; it is a part of the .NET Framework.  Developers are free to choose the approach that best suits their particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

No, basically. This code is compiled as:

```cs
string.Concat(string.Concat("" + x1, x2), x3);
```

However, if you did

```cs
string concat = x1 + x2 + x2;
```

it would be compiled more reasonably as a single call:

```cs
string concat = string.Concat(x1, x2, x3);
```